# What is "would + verb" being used in these examples?

Tags: verbs, would

How do you describe the verb "would return" in the following?

> Martin would get a minor penalty for the infraction, and during the ensuing power play, Zach Hyman would block a Brent Burns shot and drop to the ice in a heap. Both Hyman and Wingels **would return** later in the period.

Comment: What do you mean by "describe"? I'm confused. Do you want an explanation of why it is used there?

Comment: It's a generic usage. This use of _would_ can describe either (a) a fantasy that the speaker is relating, or (b) a frequent generic situation in past experience that the speaker is relating. Since there is in most cases little difference between narrative memory and fantasy (see Loftus et al), the distinction is a matter of context only. Due to the specificity of the events in this example, though, there is very little context for (b) here, so it wouldn't occur to most people.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it "future historic," but **"future in the past"** is less ambiguous. All the verbs in that passage are the same: *would get, would block, would return.*

It is describing a future event from the point of view of the speaker, who is in the past.

> Jones thought about watching the match on TV. But he already knew what would happen.

Here, we are describing Jones from our point of view. He's in the past. If we add his future to that description, we need your tense:

> Martin would get a minor penalty for [an] infraction, and during the ensuing power play, Zach Hyman would block a Brent Burns shot and drop to the ice in a heap. Both Hyman and Wingels would return later in the period.

Comment: Another example: "Alexander Hamilton was the Secretary of the Treasury in the administration of President George Washington, from 1789 to 1795.  He would later be killed in a duel with Vice President Aaron Burr (in 1804)."  I.e., the duel was in the future from the point of view of 1795.

Answer (score 0):

The particular example here describes a hockey game between the Totonto Maple Leafs and the San Jose Sharks from a couple of days ago. I have seen sportswriters fall into this odd use of conditional in situations where they are recounting specific events and then want to jump ahead in their account to subsequent events but worry that continuing in the same tense might not adequately reflect the temporal reference point previously established. So instead they recount those subsequent events in the conditional form of what "would" happen from that fixed reference point.

In the particular instance you cite, Matt Martin of the Leafs crashed Tommy Wingels of the Sharks into the Plexiglas wall of the rink (an infraction of the rules, known as "boarding") just 2 minutes, 21 seconds into the game. Time stood still, and the sportswriter addressed future developments in the game as from that moment of eerie quiet and frozen time. Martin would receive a penalty, the Sharks would go on a power play (which just means that they would have a one-man advantage on the ice for the duration of the penalty to Martin), a Sharks player would take a shot that temporarily knocked a defending Leafs player out of action, and both injured players would return to the ice before the first period ended. (Each of the three periods in a game is 20 minutes long.)

All of these things would happen because they did happen. But at 2:21 of the first period of the Maple Leafs–Sharks game, no one knew that they would. You can certainly make a case for using "future from a past fixed point" perspective in certain situations—"Following the cherry tree incident, the lad would eventually go on to become President of the United States"—but it has a tendentiousness or excessive dramaticality that I don't like, and there is no reason the author couldn't simply have put the narrative this way:

> Martin received a minor penalty for the infraction. During the ensuing power play, Zach Hyman blocked a Brent Burns shot and dropped to the ice in a heap. Both Hyman and Wingels returned later in the period.

But the intoxicating appeal of speaking sonorously of the future now past from a past farther past makes Nostradamuses or Amazing Kreskins of many an ink-stained wretch in the present.